# How to convert point shapefile to polygon

Tags: shapefile

I have United kingdom point shapefile, I want to know how to convert that into polygon file.
Currently I am working on web project, where I need to outline city boundaries on google map.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/point-to-polygon-part-i/) may be of help

Comment: What do the points represent?  If they are just centroids, the best you could do is some kind of voronoi tessellation.